# CameraDevice failing to create session [Camera2]

Tags: java, android, camera, camera2

I'm trying to use the `Camera2` API to stream camera data to a `SurfaceView`. I'm following this guide: [Camera2 guide](http://pierrchen.blogspot.com.au/2015/01/android-camera2-api-explained.html)

I cannot get past `step 5`

> MainActivity.java::onCreate()

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
```

> MainActivity.java::onClick()

```
for (String id : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
    CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(id);

    Integer direction = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);

    if (direction != null && direction == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK) {
        if (checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.CAMERA") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            manager.openCamera(id, new StateCallback(), null);

        break;
    }
}
```

> MainActivity.java.StateCallback::onOpened(CameraDevice camera)

```
List<Surface> surfaces = new LinkedList<>();
surfaces.add(surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());

CaptureRequest.Builder builder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
builder.addTarget(surfaces.get(0));

camera.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Configured");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Configured failed"); // Ends up in this function :(
    }
    }, null);
```

The program ends up in the `onConfigureFailed()` function. I don't know what could be the error, and I don't know how to check what is.

My guess would be that I'm missing something in the `CaptureRequest`, but I have no idea what.

I'm running on a [Samsung Galaxy S4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S4).

Comment: Please add logcat output from when you see the failure. The camera service should have more information in logcat about why the session cannot be created.

Comment: hello @Arbitur i am having same issue with s4 , did you find any clue on that ?

Answer (score 0):

add to onConfigured:

```
  if (null == cameraDevice) {
        Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
        return;
    }
    captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    try {
        cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `onConfigureFailed()` like this:

```
   @Override
   public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
       ImageReader mReader = ImageReader.newInstance(640, 480, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
       takePicture() // function to get image
       createCameraPreview(); // function to set camera Preview on screen
   }
```

Call createCameraPreview function to restart the camera, otherwise, it will stay stuck.
You can change the ImageReader with new values

```
ImageReader mReader = ImageReader.newInstance(640, 480, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
```

And call the `takePicture()` function again so that user don't have to click again to capture image.